# What does [] in function signature do in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, quickbooks

I am studying QuickBooks SDK code and saw this line:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);
```

> What is confusing me is the **[In]** in the function signature

---

I don't know where to look to learn what this is.
Can someone explain it or point me to the docs to read about it?

I am studying the code from 
[SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent_vs03](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples/tree/master/qbdt/c-sharp/qbXML/SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent_vs03)

The line is in the SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent_vs03.cs file

Comment: It's an attribute being applied to that method parameter (`lpMsg`) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the code between `[]` are attributes. See [InAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [OutAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more information.

Comment: [Not always](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).  [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

Comment: For this particular line of code I believe that's what it is. Thanks jri